# laravel lost password issue

Tags: forms, email, authentication, laravel

im making an authentification form where i have to add the lost password form so i found a tutorial that im folowing but im not getting the result

http://culttt.com/2013/09/23/password-reminders-reset-laravel-4/

when i enter teh email and press the button

```
Route::post('password', function()
{
$credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));
return Password::remind($credentials);
});
```

it says that This super simple method uses Laravel’s input reminder functionality to add the email to the reminder table we created earlier and send the email. You might get an exception saying that you haven’t set up your sender address yet. To fix this, go to app/config/mail.php and fill in the relevant details.

but im getting a view with " reminders.user " can someone help :) thx

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an INVALID_USER message.

Your lang/reminders.php file is not in place, so it is showing the key 'reminders.user' instead of "We can't find a user with that e-mail address.".